# Every time need to rebuild project to reflect changes in Android Studio Chipmunk

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, android-studio-chipmunk

I am using Android Studio Chipmunk (2021.2.1 Patch 1) stable version

[image: Android studio version chipmunk]

Whenever I do any changes in Kotlin or XML file and run the project then changes don't reflect in app unless and until I rebuild the project from `Build -> Rebuild Project`.

Every time I have to rebuild project if I have done any changes in code.

I have already tried with `File -> Invalidate Caches -> Invalidate and restart`

Comment: I had this very ennoying problem way before `Patch 1` and can't remember what was the reason: gradle build cache or offline mode or studio?
`Patch 2` is released. If it does not help, try to delete `.idea` folder.

Comment: I'm having the same problem but on macOS, unfortunately didn't find a solution yet

Answer (score 3):

I was with the same problem, needed rebuild my project every change, but I find the solution.

1. Go to edit configurations to build
2. Android App -> app
3. Scroll to bottom page
4. Verify if has any task at "Before launch"
5. if have nothing, click on add icon and add "Gradle-aware Make"

This solve my problem

Comment: Quick tip on image links: where it says "enter image description here", this is a placeholder for you to fill in, so that site visitors with screen-readers can see a description of what the image contains.

Answer (score 2):

When I update my android studio, then the latest changes are not deploying so After lots of research and experiment,

I found this solution then my Android Studio working fine. You can also try this.

Firstly open from here : [image: Firstly open from here]

And then enable from here : [image: And then enable from here]

Comment: It is better to include a description if the images ever becomes unavailable. For those wondering, the solution involves enabling "Install for all users" in the Run configuration of the app.
I confirm it worked for me